# How and where can i get the original version of Shiva Mahapurana?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana

Please help me to get the original version of Shiva Mahapurana. And please let me know how to recognise the original version ?

Comment: What do you mean  by "original version"?

Comment: Try searching in Gita press online.

Comment: Original are in Sanskrit and may be found in big Shiva Temples like of Amarnath or Varanasi

Comment: Is there any way to get it online ?